# Strange folder structure when adding language

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

My app is Base language English. 
I have added German, and Xcode generated automatically a folder structure that doesn't correspond to what the documentation says. (cf screenshots from Xcode and Finder).

When I run genstrings, it only generates stuff for the english strings (the german remains empty).
I manually copy then the English strings into the German strings, but Export ignores the German strings in the cliff file

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, the de.lproj folder should be at the same level as the en.lproj folder, not a subdirectory of it. Second, you can choose when exporting to XLIFF if you want to export existing translations or the development language only. You may not be seeing that option since the folder layout is currently incorrect.

[image: Xcode XLIFF export options]

Comment: The folder structure was created by Xcode automatically!!

Comment: Xcode does weird things sometimes. Either way, you have to manually fix the project structure to get things working correctly.